# USB SSH Connection refused/No route to host

Tags: usb, ssh, headless

I know this has been asked before but I can't find a solution that works for me so I'm going to try asking again. I'm using a Pi Zero W headless and trying to SSH into it from my Ubuntu 18.04 machine via USB. I've set IPv4 to `link-local` and set IPv6 to `disabled`.

Running `ifconfig -a` shows my Pi as `enp2s0f0u1` with an IP `169.254.X.X` so I know the addressing is working. When I run `ssh pi@169.254.X.X` I get `Connection refused`. If I run `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` I get `No route to host`.

Any help or recommendations would be appreciated

Edit:

**Ubuntu**

`ifconfig`

```
enp9s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.13.44 netmask 255.255.0.0 broadcast 192.168.255.255
        inet6 fe80::b49e::2839::1fcd::30eb prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e0:d5:5e:6f:84:37 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1718078 bytes 144625927 (144.6 MB)
        RX errors 0 dropped 100 overruns 0 frame 0
        TX packets 1667922 bytes 139285417 (139.2 MB)
        TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop txqueuelen 1000 (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 71351 bytes 5099667 (5.0 MB)
        RX errors 0 dropped 100 overruns 0 frame 0
        TX packets 71351 bytes 5099667 (5.0 MB)
        TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

`ip route`

```
169.254.0.0/16 dev enps0 scope link metric 1000
192.168.0.0/16 dev enps0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.13.44 metric 100
```

**Raspberry Pi**

`ifconfig`

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop txqueuelen 1000 (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0 B)
        RX errors 0 dropped 100 overruns 0 frame 0
        TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0 B)
        TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

usb0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        ether 1a:61:7f:e8:cf:d1 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0 B)
        RX errors 0 dropped 100 overruns 0 frame 0
        TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0 B)
        TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

`ip route` shows nothing

Comment: 'connection refused' seems to indicate that the SSH server on the Pi0 is not active. Did you activate it? If you did, have you verified it's active?

Comment: I have yeah I went through `raspi-config` and turned ssh on. I also checked status of sshd and it's active

Comment: IP starting with 169 is a self assigned address. Can you get a good IP address from a DHCP server and try again? What is the address of the Ubuntu machine? If they are not on the same subnet, they cannot see each other.

Comment: My Ubuntu machine is on /24 subnet. How would I go about finding a good IP from DHCP? Is that an nmap scan or is that a static IP I need to assign? (Sorry if that's a dumb question, still trying to learn all this stuff)

Comment: Just kidding, my Ubuntu machine is on /16 subnet

Comment: An nmap scan sounds good, but routers usually already have a list of active DHCP clients. Simply pick one that's unused and within your subnet and use that as a static IP.

Comment: Should I assign that static IP to the `usb0` interface in `dhcpcd.conf`

Comment: Please don't use a static ip address. Most questions on this site are about static ip addresses. It does not make things simpler. On the contrary, it makes things more complicated if you do not understand detailed networking. The computer knows it better what it needs. Please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/120400/edit) your question and add the output of this two commands on the RasPi and on the Ubuntu device to it: `ip addr` and `ip route`.

Comment: I (intentionally) don't have internet access on my Ubuntu device or the Pi so I can't access those outputs without physically typing out each one... but I'll add some information about those outputs to the question

Comment: It would really help if you ***copied and pasted*** the actual output of your commands into the question instead of re-typing or summarizing. No one cares (or can use) your private IPv4 *link-local* addresses to play tricks on you - just put them in your Q please.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: In your question, you state "Pi as enp2s0f0u1 with an IP 169.254.X.X" but in the ifconfig output later in the question, no such interface or address exists.  Are you sure you have an interface configured on the pi?  If you're trying to connect over USB, shouldn't an address be assigned to usb0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Running ifconfig -a shows my Pi as enp2s0f0u1 with an IP 169.254.X.X

This is the interface and its ip address on the Ubuntu device. It does not show anything about the RasPi. Your RasPi shows interface **usb0** without an ip address. This cannot work. **usb0** must have an ip address. Please fix the connection on the RasPi so that it get an ip address from the link-local address block 169.254.0.0/16.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:-

1. Turn off your Raspberry Pi
2. Remove your SD card and put into a card reader and connect to the computer.
3. create an empty file named **ssh**  inside the **boot directory**.
4. put the  SD card again into the raspberry pi.
5. Now connect your raspberry pi via ssh

Comment: This was like the first step that I tried and it didn't work...